# Grab nth occurrence in between two patterns using awk or sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have an issue where I want to parse through the output from a file and I want to grab the nth occurrence of text in between two patterns preferably using awk or sed

```
category
1
s
t
done
category
2
n
d
done
category
3
r
d
done
category
4
t
h
done
```

Let's just say for this example I want to grab the third occurrence of text in between category and done, essentially the output would be

```
category
3
r
d
done
```

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Do you have code you've tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
'sed -n '/category/{:a;N;/done/!ba;x;s/^/x/;/^x\{3\}$/{x;p;q};x}' file
```

Turn off automatic printing by using the `-n` option. Gather up lines between `category` and `done`. Store a counter in the hold space and when it reaches 3 print the collection in the pattern space and quit.

Or if you prefer awk:

```
awk  '/^category/,/^done/{if(++m==1)n++;if(n==3)print;if(/^done/)m=0}'  file
```

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else just use awk or you'll find the tiniest requirements change (e.g. print the line numbers too) requires a total re-write of your script, possibly in a different language. Doing anything in sed that requires more than "s" and "g" commands is a waste of time.

Comment: the awk script will keep printing after the 'done" if there's tes=xt between done and the next category. It would also print the wrong block if category can exist without a done. don't know what the sed scripts would do.

Comment: @EdMorton I believe printing is narrowed to between `category` and `done`, If there is no `done` this may be what the user requires.

Comment: Try it with a file with 2 "category" lines before the first "done". It'll print the 2nd category->done block instead of the 3rd.

Comment: I used this awk method

awk  '/^category/,/^done/{if(/^category/)n++;if(n==3)print}'  file 

Thanks for the response

Comment: just curious: why? it's testing the same condition multiple times and won't work if your input file changes slightly. If you're happy with a solution that only works with exactly the posted input format, @sputnik's solution is much more concise.

Comment: can you please explain both the sed commands..that will be really informative & helpful !

Answer (score 7):

Try doing this :

```
 awk -v n=3 '/^category/{l++} (l==n){print}' file.txt
```

Or more cryptic :

```
awk -v n=3 '/^category/{l++} l==n' file.txt
```

If your file is big :

```
awk -v n=3 '/^category/{l++} l>n{exit} l==n' file.txt
```

Comment: Sorry lets say that the beginning and end are not the same word, I want the third occurrence of what comes in between category and done.

Comment: `/^category/` mean a string beginning with "category", it's really different than a line _containing_ category. So no need any modification, the script still works AS IS.

Comment: That will work with the posted sample input but won't work if there cane be occurrences of category without done or text between done and category.

Answer (score 2):

If your file doesn't contain any null characters, here's on way using `GNU sed`. This will find the *third* occurrence of a pattern range. However, you can easily modify this to get any occurrence you'd like.

```
sed -n '/^category/ { x; s/^/\x0/; /^\x0\{3\}$/ { x; :a; p; /done/q; n; ba }; x }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
category
3
r
d
done
```

Explanation:

Turn off default printing with the `-n` switch. Match the word 'category' at the start of a line. Swap the pattern space with the hold space and append a null character to the start of the pattern. In the example, if the pattern then contains two leading null characters, pull the pattern out of holdspace. Now create a loop and print the contents of the pattern space until the last pattern is matched. When this last pattern is found, `sed` will quit. If it's not found `sed` will continue to read the next line of input in and continue in its loop.

Comment: I'd like it to print the 3rd occurrence but only if the 2nd occurrence contained the word "awk". How would I modify that sed command to do that? In awk I'd simply create a "prevRec" variable to store the previous record and add an `if (prevRec ~ /awk/)` before the print.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v tgt=3 '
/^category$/ { fnd=1; rec="" }

fnd {
   rec = rec $0 ORS
   if (/^done$/) {
      if (++cnt == tgt) {
         printf "%s",rec
         exit
      }
      fnd = 0
   }
}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk you can set the the record separator to a regular expression:

```
<file awk 'NR==n+1 { print rt, $0 } { rt = RT }' RS='\\<category' ORS='' n=3
```

Output:

```
category 
3
r
d
done
```

`RT` is the matched record separator. Note that the record relative to `n` will be off by one as the first record refers to what precedes the first `RS`.

#### Edit

As per Ed's comment, this will not work when the records have other data in between them, e.g.:

```
category
1
s
t
done
category
2
n
d
done

foo

category
3
r
d
done

bar
category
4
t
h
done
```

One way to get around this is to clean up the input with a second (or first) awk:

```
<file awk '/^category$/,/^done$/' |
  awk 'NR==n+1 { print rt, $0 } { rt = RT }' RS='\\<category' ORS='' n=3
```

Output:

```
category 
3
r
d
done
```

#### Edit 2

As *Ed* has noted in the comments, the above methods do not search for the ending pattern. One way to do this, which hasn't been covered by the other answers, is with `getline` (note that there are some [caveats](http://awk.info/?tip/getline) with awk getline):

```
<file awk '
  /^category$/ {
    v = $0
    while(!/^done$/) { 
      if(!getline) 
        exit
      v = v ORS $0
    }
    if(++nr == n) 
      print v
}' n=3
```

On one line:

```
<file awk '/^category$/ { v = $0; while(!/^done$/) { if(!getline) exit; v = v ORS $0 } if(++nr == n)  print v }' n=3
```

Comment: that will print the text between occurrences of the word category, not between category and done. In the posted input it doesn't matter but in general it could, e.g. if f there can be other text between done and category or occurrences of category without an associated done.

Comment: @EdMorton: True. One possible fix is to clean up the input first, see edit.

Comment: It would still fail and print the 2nd record instead of the 3rd one if you added a "category" line before the first "done" in your sample input, e.g. between the "s" and "t" lines.

Comment: @EdMorton: Right, I see your point, the ending pattern is not searched for. I've added a `getline` alternative that does search for `done`.

Comment: IMHO the non-getline version I posted is simpler and it doesn't have all the getline caveats (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline). I expect you posted that just as a contrast to the other solutions but for the OPs benefit I think it's worth explicitly mentioning that it comes with some baggage.

Comment: @EdMorton: Indeed, I meant it as a contrast. 
I hadn't realized  getline had this many potential issues, depending on what the OP is doing this may or may not be a problem. I'll put a warning and reference on the answer. Nice post by the way.

Comment: 1) Thanks. 2) Yeah, getline is a can of worms. It's very useful when used appropriately, though, much like a hand grenade.